# Does tensorflow c++ API support automatic differentiation for backpropagation?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, backpropagation, gradient-descent

Does tensor-flow C++ API support automatic differentiation to back-propagate the gradient?
If I write a graph in c++ and would like to run it in a c++ code (not in python!) will automatic differentiation work?

Let's suppose every op in the graph has a gradient implementation.

I think the documentation regarding what tensor-flow C++ API can and can't do is is very poor.

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Technically* it can, but AFAIK the automatic differentiation is only "configured" in Python. What I mean by this is that, at a lower level, each TensorFlow operation does *not* declare itself what its gradient is (that is, the corresponding operation that computes its gradient). That is instead declared at Python level. For example, you can take a look at [`math_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py). You will see that, among other things, there are several functions decorated with `@ops.RegisterGradient(...)`. What this decorator does is adding that function to a global registry (in Python) of operations and their gradients. So, for example, optimizer classes are largely implemented in Python, since they make use of this registry to build the backpropagation computation (as opposed to making use of native TensorFlow primitives to that end, which do not exist).

So the point is that you can do the same computations using the same ops (which are then implemented with the same kernels), but I don't think that C++ has (or will ever have) such gradient registry (and optimizer classes), so you would need to work out or copy that backpropagation construction by yourself. In general, the C++ API is not well suited to building the computation graph.

Now a different question (and maybe this was what you were asking about in the first place) is whether you can run an already existing graph that does backpropagation in C++. By this I mean building a computation graph in Python, creating an optimizer (which in turn creates the necessary operations in the graph to compute the gradient and update the variables) and exporting the graph, then load that graph in C++ and run it. That is entirely possible and no different to running any other kind of thing in TensorFlow C++.

Comment: Thank you very much @jdehesa, exactly what I needed! So @ops.RegisterGradient(...) tells me that the op in python has a gradient implementation, but how to identify GPU support?

Comment: Another question: while defining the graph in python I can also use operations/gradient that don"t have a c++ implementation, right?

Comment: @Ceveloper About GPU support, that's another matter... There is no straightforward support in Python (see [#2502](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2502), with a link to a proposed solution requiring native support). You can also browse the [kernels code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v1.8.0/tensorflow/core/kernels) and see what kernels are registered for each op... In C++ apparently you can gather that information from `KernelsRegisteredForOp` (defined in [`op_kernel.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h)).

Comment: @Ceveloper About second question, in general TF Python functions are "translated" to one or more standard graph ops with implementations in C++ or CUDA, so you can always export the graph and run it in C++. The exception is [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), which lets you to define custom ops with Python code. As noted in the docs, that op cannot be serialized to `GraphDef` and can only be used within the same Python process where it is defined (but it lets you to define a [custom gradient](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342)).

Comment: Very useful information. I plan to use the tf.linalg.expm in a graph, with GPU and gradient, but as I understand both are not supported. @jdehesa can you maybe give me a practical advice about how to solve this? I could add the gradient (maybe as custom op in c++), but what to do for the GPU? Tensorflow documentation states that  related information can be found on tensorflow/python/ops/gen_linalg_ops.py, but this file doesn't exist in the named repository. There are related files but they don't contain the information I need.

Comment: @Ceveloper `gen_*` files are generated during TF compilation. `expm` is the op `MatrixExponential`, implemented in [`kernels/matrix_exponential_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/matrix_exponential_op.cc). Indeed, I can't find a GPU kernel nor a `RegisterGradient` for it. You _can_ extend TF with your own ops at C++ level (or even just add a GPU kernel for a existing op), see [Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), then register the gradient and use it from Python or C++ as long as you load your extension lib.

Comment: @Ceveloper (about `gen_*` files, `gen_linalg_ops.py` is generated from [`ops/linalg_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/core/ops/linalg_ops.cc), which defines `MatrixExponential`, snake-cased to `matrix_exponential` in Python, then [`linalg_impl.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg/linalg_impl.py), a regular Python module, defines `expm` as `gen_linalg_ops.matrix_exponential`)

Comment: Great @jdehesa, so I will extend the python op with gradient and GPU version in C++, build the computation graph in python, and use it in C++. But what's the best way to load the graph in C++? I'm only aware of the possibility to store the graph from python in a binary file, are there better options? A shared library would be perfect.

Comment: @Ceveloper Loading the GraphDef protocol buffer file is how I've been doing it so far. It should be quite simple and flexible. I'm not sure if serialization works any different when custom ops are involved, but in principle I don't think it should...

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa for the help!! Now everything is clear